# Derivation of pressure balance equation for a toroidal geometry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, plasma-physics, fusion, magnetohydrodynamics

Derivation of pressure balance equation in toroidal geometry

$$
\boxed{
\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}r} + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \left( \frac{B_{\phi}^2}{2\mu_0} \right) + \frac{B_{\theta}}{\mu_0r} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \left( rB_{\theta} \right) = 0
} 
\tag{1}
$$

Here, $\phi$ is the toroidal angle and $\theta$ is the poloidal angle in the right-handed axis-symmetric toroidal coordinate system.

Approach:

$$
\nabla p = \vec{j} \times \vec{B} \tag{2}
$$

Using Ampere's Law,

$$
\vec{j} = \frac{1}{\mu_0} \nabla \times \vec{B} \tag{3}
$$

Substitute Eq.(3) in Eq.(2) to get,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla p &= \frac{1}{\mu_0} \left( \nabla \times \vec{B} \right) \times \vec{B} \\
&= -\nabla \frac{B^2}{2\mu_0} + \frac{1}{\mu_0} \left( \vec{B} \cdot \nabla \right) \vec{B}
\end{aligned}
\tag{4}
$$

How to get derive equation (1) from equation (4)? Specially the components of $\vec{B}$ in $\phi$ and $\theta$ direction.

Ref: TOKAMAKS - John Wesson, 3rd Edition, Page 116

Comment: Leave the equation in the first of the two forms shown for Equation 4 then expand $\nabla \times \mathbf{B}$ in cylindrical coordinates before expanding the cross-product components with the last $\mathbf{B}$.  That will give you Equation 1.